# Plot bar and line in same plot, different y-axes without pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

Data for bar chart:

```
sum_values = {2000: 258004, 2001: 243411, 2002: 234801, 2003: 231303, 2004: 235103, 2005: 234102, 2006: 236045, 2007: 262238, 2008: 317133, 2009: 337785, 2010: 379818, 2011: 425237, 2012: 446610}
```

Data for line chart:

```
avg_values = {'2006': 29034, '2007': 29612, '2008': 28551, '2009': 39320, '2010': 30061, '2011': 24331, '2012': 23579, '2013': 17552, '2014': 17673, '2015': 19620, '2016': 20894}
```

Snippet of my graphing codes:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
barchart = plt.bar(list(sum_values.keys()), list(sum_values.values()), color='red')
linechart = plt.plot(list(sum_values.values()), color='blue')
```

**Screenshot of my graphing result:**
[image: Screenshot of my graphing result]

- How can I plot the line chart with secondary y axis?
- As the x-values for the two charts are different, how can I plot for the common x values only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem is, that the keys in your barchart data are of type `string`. Besides that, you don't provide x values for your line plot, so `avg_values` is plotted simply over its indices.
So assumed you fix the data type issue, this code should work:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

barchart = plt.bar(sum_values.keys(), sum_values.values(), color='red')
plt.twinx()
linechart = plt.plot(avg_values.keys(), avg_values.values(), color='blue')
```

Note that you don't need to make lists from the keys or values of a dict.

However, if you can't change the data type of the `sum_values.keys()` for whatever reason, you could cast the type to int inline of the barplot command like this:

```
barchart = plt.bar(list(map(int, sum_values.keys())), sum_values.values(), color='red')
```

(In case of the map object, you do need to make a list of its result)

[image]

For viewing the common x values part only,  you can set the x axis limits after calculating the common x values like:

```
commonx = [a for a in avg_values.keys() if a in sum_values.keys()]
plt.xlim(min(commonx) - .5, max(commonx) + .5)
```

[image]

Comment: I have converted the keys for my line chart/ avg_values to int, and used your suggested codes to plot twin charts in the same graph. Noticed that the x-values has decimals .5 for some of the values (e.g. 2002.5, 2007.5), why is that so? I also tried to compute for commonx but the following error appears: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable, any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: First question: because x axis is of type float and ticjs are placed automatically. But you can control this manually, too. Second question: hard to tell without the code which produces this error. The only thing I can say is that the code I posted does not throw an error.

Comment: I tried running simple codes like "min([1, 2, 3])" and it throws the same error. What is happening? @SpghttCd

Comment: You probably defined variables like `min` or `sum` before and now want to use these python keywords in their original meaning. You can e.g. `del(min)` to throw away your variable with this bad chosen name and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Data preparation for filtering the common years:

```
sum_values = {2000: 258004, 2001: 243411, 2002: 234801, 2003: 231303, 2004: 235103, 2005: 234102, 2006: 236045, 2007: 262238, 2008: 317133, 2009: 337785, 2010: 379818, 2011: 425237, 2012: 446610}
avg_values = {'2006': 29034, '2007': 29612, '2008': 28551, '2009': 39320, '2010': 30061, '2011': 24331, '2012': 23579, '2013': 17552, '2014': 17673, '2015': 19620, '2016': 20894}

from collections import OrderedDict
avg_values = {int(k):v for k,v in avg_values.items() if int(k) in sum_values.keys()}
sum_values = {k:v for k,v in sum_values.items() if k in avg_values.keys()}

sum_values=OrderedDict(sorted(sum_values.items()))  
avg_values=OrderedDict(sorted(avg_values.items()))
```

Plotting the common years with secondary axis!

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(5,5))
barchart = plt.bar(avg_values.keys(), avg_values.values(), color='red')
plt.twinx()

linechart = plt.plot(sum_values.keys(), sum_values.values(), color='blue',label='Sum')
```

[image]