# Creating a bar chart with 2 y axes from lists using matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, bar-chart, yaxis

I need to make the following chart: Number of Companies, Donations vs Year as a bar chart.

The following is my data:

```
Year = [2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]
No_Companies = [123558,132335,147606,155790,161211,169784,174599,183888,198727,207317,217357,228996]
Donations=[144932,304607,642328,870509,1205382,1094624,2089240,2325322,2387036,3096069,4204255,3500766]
```

From what I have seen from other questions, most seem to have either their data in a dataframe or a list like `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]`.

How can I get the chart I need from the data I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link out: [Plot bar and line in same plot, different y-axes using matplotlib (no pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901718/plot-bar-and-line-in-same-plot-different-y-axes-using-matplotlib-no-pandas)

The implementation can be done as follows:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

barchart = plt.bar(Year, No_Companies, color='red')
plt.ylabel('No Companies')
plt.twinx()
barchart1 = plt.bar(Year, Donations, color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Donations')
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNkxX.png)